# Access denied to remote MySQL connection request

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database (v5.5.41) setup on a remote server and an application connects to the DB from another server to run some queries. It's been working fine but recently my DB server got a new IP address. My application can't connect to the DB anymore, the connection times out.

The application is using the DNS name of the server, not a hard-coded IP, so there shouldn't be a problem. In any case, if I run this from the application server:

```
mysql -u app_user -h mydb.myhost.com -p
```

then I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'app_user'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

If it was having trouble finding the new IP, then that command would probably just hang and timeout, so it seems to be an authentication issue. **My password is definitely correct,** but the application is using the same password as when the app was connecting successfully so it's not an issue of mistyping it.

I've tried deleting the user `app_user` from the database and re-creating, exactly as I did in the beginning:

```
CREATE USER 'app_user'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'app_user'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I'm not sure if the DB server IP change is just a coincidence, and maybe there's some other issue.

The entry for `app_user` in `select user, host from mysql.user` shows the same IP address as in the `Access Denied` message above. For what it's worth, I tried changing the DB user host to `*` and got `Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`.

Could this have something to do with SSL being required by connection attempts from this user?

Comment: Possibly your ip address has changed (the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx part). You can change the permissions to allow a user called app_user@* and see if it lets you connect.

Comment: Try this one-liner here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31375124/1816093 Of course change dbname and username but not `%`

Comment: You really want him to open all the gates for having anyone bored having fun on his SQL-Server? Not a good Idea Drew. Better Idea is to use Giles Method - and if he got no static IP, he should try a proxy for his App - maybe he can use his own Server as Proxy.

Comment: U mean anyone bored that has that user password @Bioshade

Comment: Anyone who got a gaming graphics card who isn't trying to log in to a ford nox saved MySQL-Server takes like 10 Minutes to crack a 8 chars long pass. Half a day for 16 chars. The user pass isn't required at all.

Comment: Well those same GPUs would bring down all mysql servers now wouldn't they?

Comment: And they could spoof sessions and ip addresses. But you have 3 mysql posts so I'll defer to you

Comment: They need half a day for a medium save pass. So what is harder to crack: That connection they don't need to know the IP they have to spoof, or the connection they need to spoof up to 4.294.967.296 IPv4-Adresses and half a day for 16 chars long pass'? Anyone should see that "%" is NEVER a good Idea to something with rights beside just reading.

@RTF: Did your Server changed? Maybe it wasn't only the IP. Maybe SSL is deactivated on your current SQL-Server. This would lead to that error-message.

Comment: My servers on AWS EC2 and I have firewall rules in place, so the DB host restriction is probably redundant anyway. I think I'll stick with `%` to make life easier for myself in case my app server IP (or anything else) changes. @DrewPierce thanks, that at least put me on the right track, it's the REQUIRE SSL option causing problems. I guess I have to create a new server key, maybe?

Comment: When on ec2 i go for creating an explicit user/host combo in mysql.user as painful as it can be

Comment: RTF: This would mean you bound your Server-cert to the IP-Adress, not to the host. This would mean you get an untrusted SSL-connection which gets refused, even your own Server is having the wrong cert. And I really advice you not to use "%" with those rights set.

Comment: Bind it to the host, change that elsewhere in DNS to go after the Elastic IP of the day

Comment: But none of this matters cuz QUAD GeoForce cards are hacking thru anyway, right :)

Comment: Drew Pierce, it wasn't a joke. Somewhen you will get it, but most likely you will learn it the ultra hard way - by getting hacked. But thats your business.

Comment: I am no stranger to security. Didn't spend years in PKI coding to get it now

Comment: If you were no stranger to it, you would agree with me since im a CEH. All you do is making bad jokes about security.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the REQUIRE SSL in the privileges for my user. Without it, I could connect just fine. I got things working **again** by putting my client-cert.pem and client-key.pem files on the application server, updated `my.cnf` by adding:

```
ssl-cert = /path/to/client-cert.pem
ssl-key  = /path/to/client-key.pem
```

...under the `[client]` section and restarted the mysql server.

However, I still don't understand why I was able to connect successfully **before** when I had done none of these things.